# How to use the to_date in Rails in English date

Tags: ruby-on-rails, date

I am trying to change a string like this "05/09/14" to a date object using `to_date` for example:

`"05/09/14".to_date` but I am getting the wrong format, I end up with `14 Sep 0005`

Can anybody point me in the right direction?

thanks,

Answer (score 2, accepted):

use this :

```
Date.strptime("05/09/14", "%d/%m/%y")
```

this will tell rails about the format in which you want to parse your date string.